# Why is every action considered to be in the support while calculating mixed strategy equilibrium?

Tags: game-theory

While evaluating the mixed strategy equilibrium, in most of the cases, we consider that all actions of a player are in the *support* of the equilibrium.Is it always so? 
I was going through a problem (36.1, Chapter 3 in Ariel Rubinstein’s *A Course in Game Theory*) where the mixed strategy equilibrium was calculated by considering all the possible actions in the support of the probability distribution. I was able to reach to this solution using the basic theory, but I cannot prove that every action will be in the support.
Here I am borrowing the definition of *support* from Ariel Rubinstein’s *A Course in Game Theory.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not, only in intro problems.

You have already seen counterexamples: The prisoner's dilemma has an equilibrium, yet it does not have full support. (But it is a pure strategy equilibrium! So? All pure strategies are just very particular mixed strategies.)

Mixed strategies with full support are called completely mixed strategies.

It is a good exercise to show that strictly dominated pure strategies are never in the support of mixed equilibrium strategies. Using this you yourself can construct a simple example where the only equilibrium is a mixed but not completely mixed strategy profile.